# Read logs from recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, logging

I want to read logs of Android devices having stuck at the boot logo, but I don't have ADB access.

Is it possible to read logs displayed by logcat in recovery by mounting `/system` partition?

Comment: A more recent answer was given here by using *pstore*: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213336/how-can-i-enable-last-kmsg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files (if they are considered as such) to which logs are written by the device are not in `/system` but in `/dev/log`.

These "files" are reset at every boot, so unless the device you have has a boot-time script that automatically saves logs to a file in, say, `/sdcard`, there is sadly no way to retrieve the logs you want while in recovery.

Comment: While true, this doesn't tell the whole story because there is at least one way to see it regardless of it being saved: http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/liveboot-t2976189/post57570477

Answer (score 0):

With TWRP, going Advanced → Copy Log could be a solution.