# How can I enable last_kmsg?

Tags: file-system, lineageos, kernel, logging, diagnostics

I'm trying to diagnose a random reboot on LineageOS 14. `last_kmsg` is not in `/proc`, nor it is in `/sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops`.

**EDIT:**

```
~# mount | grep PSTORE
~# mkdir /mnt/pstore && mount pstore -t pstore /mnt/pstore && ls /mnt/pstore
mount: 'pstore'->'/mnt/pstore': No such device
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Back in 2012, `/proc/last_kmsg` <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/c672528aec4a1cf6f3df7a6022e6823a20b20f8e))</sup> used to be a dump of kernel console messages, exported after reboots by Android's `ram_console` functionality (CONFIG_ANDROID_RAM_CONSOLE), which used `persistent_ram` (CONFIG_ANDROID_PERSISTENT_RAM) to handle a block of RAM that wasn't erased across reboots <sup>([2](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/linux-linaro/+spec/android-ram-console))</sup>.

`persistent_ram` was based on Linux upstream RAMOOPS code which logged **panic and oops** messages to RAM. RAMOOPS was deprecated in favor of PSTORE <sup>([3](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/9ba80d99c86f1b76df891afdf39b44df38bbd35b))</sup> (memory handling) and PSTORE_RAM <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/1894a253db97059bc299b834b76f665bc6586b1d))</sup> (logging panics/oops to `pstore/dmesg-ramoops`). Later PSTORE_CONSOLE support was added <sup>([5](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/b5d38e9bf1b0c4db19e336b59b38dfb5d28bf1bf), [6](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/f29e5956aebafe63f81e80f972c44c4a666e5c7f))</sup> to log not only the panics/oops, but all kernel console messages to `pstore/console-ramoops-N` which can be read later by mounting `pstore` <sup>([7](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.1/Documentation/admin-guide/ramoops.rst#reading-the-data))</sup>. So the Android specific RAM_CONSOLE <sup>([8](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/15d76446205710ddfcba6cc9156c7883074f84b1), [9](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/d7a33d74e9913bd4d2580aff67ed7051935f546b))</sup> and PERSISTENT_RAM <sup>([10](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/cddb8751c80348df75149f44fc3bf38d3dd1f3e6))</sup> were utterly removed.

Now `pstore` also offers logging userspace messages (PSTORE_PMSG) <sup>([11](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/9d5438f462abd6398cdb7b3211bdcec271873a3b))</sup> and other features <sup>([12](https://github.com/abrt/abrt/wiki/pstore-oops))</sup>. Plus it supports multiple backends for persistent storage if supported by hardware, though SoC's on Android devices only support RAM storage (`ramoops` driver, AFAIK).

So it's not possible to enable `last_kmsg` on an upstream kernel, instead `pstore` offers a more versatile functionality.

> mount: 'pstore'->'/mnt/pstore': No such device

It shows that your kernel isn't built with `pstore` support. All you need to do is use a kernel built with [`CONFIG_PSTORE_CONSOLE`](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-4.19/fs/pstore/Kconfig#110) and optionally `CONFIG_PSTORE_RAM` (though [buggy](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/a28726b4fb624f81d637a8afb9ea12fc16500f61)). Android's `init` by-default mounts `pstore` at `/sys/fs/pstore` <sup>([13](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/rootdir/init.rc#235))</sup> from where `dmesg-ramoops` (on panics/oops only) and `console-ramoops` can be read.

You can search forums for a custom ROM shipped with such kernel. Or if you have kernel source, you can build yourself on a Linux machine.

**NOTE:** Some new devices, like Samsung, still expose `/proc/last_kmsg` interface; I'm not sure whether they use original implementation or `pstore` at back end.

---

**FURTHER READING:** [Reading kernel logs](https://docs.halium.org/en/latest/porting/debug-build/dmesg.html)

Comment: `/sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops` is only accessible if rooted ?

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually manage to set up some kind of chron job which wrote the log to a file every few seconds. I can't remember how sorry - it was more than two years ago.

The log didn't give me an answer, which I found puzzling. I wondered if the log was not being copied quick enough before the shutdown.

That might be an issue for some people, but I soon discovered the problem was very simple - the battery was faulty. This model (s5) has a removable battery, so I swapped it and the problem was gone. Do the simple things first.