# Deducing problems using device logs

Tags: custom-roms, reboot, logging

kinda new to debugging here.
I'm running a custom rom on my device and I've started to get random reboots. I wanted to look at logs and find out. But I don't really know what to look for in these logs.

Any ideas as to how I should go about doing this?

Any help would be really appreciated .

Comment: In case of reboots usually the kernel log is relevant. See for example this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213460/2241). If you can manually "trigger" the reboot also `adb logcat` may contain valuable information. Regarding the question "what is relevant": Just collect several logs right before the reboot occurs and then compare the last entries. If something is present in all logs it might be relevant.

Comment: Yeah, I had to ask around for a few telegram channels too, but I finally found out that it was just kernel panicking for weird reasons.