# How to disable automatic reboot on kernel panic?

Tags: root-access, boot-loop, 9.0-pie, magisk, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-3

Since my device was unproperly shut down because the battery stopped functioning (the battery is getting completely discharged at a level higher than 1%), it is rebooting in loops even in safe mode (more exactly it reboots about 3 to 5 seconds after finishing booting).
So it means a file or permission wasn’t properly written in /data.
But in my case, the /data partition is on the sd card thanks to Magisk root, so I have full access to it.

Using a computer, I tried to put an additional Magisk startup script which is executed at boot in order to stream kernel log to a file, but the result isn’t useful as the last line of the log file looks something like this :

```
[   72.480828] Ke
```

**So which is the command to execute or file to write in `/proc` or `/sys` in order to disable automatic reboot after a kernel panic** so the kernel finish to flush the log file ?

Comment: `last_kmsg` or `pstore` is the best ways to get kernel panic log. You don't need to write kernel log to a file. Details here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213460/218526. But you haven't stated in your question how a malfunctioning battery relates to kernel panics or reboots / bootloop and why you want to get kernel log. // Btw you can control reboot behavior on kernel panic by writing (directly or by using `sysctl`) to different files (including `panic` and `panic_on_oops`) in `/proc/sys/kernel/`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif unfortunately `last_kmsg` and `pstore` don’t return the kernel log on my device. And as I said, I suppose it’s because of the improper shutdown since I replaced by the exact same battery model from Samsung.