# Building Pixel 4a kernel

Tags: custom-roms, boot, android-10, kernel, google-pixel-4a

I'm trying to build my custom sunfish kernel on pixel 4a,
note that the system is unlocked and rooted via "Magisk",
After building success (for test I didn't change anything on kernel source) I pulled the boot.img, unpacked it replace the zImage with my new kernel (Image.lz4), packed and pushed it back to the boot partition via fastboot.
Finally reboot and the booting process stuck on "Google" logo.
Do I missed something ?
Thanks,

Comment: Build your kernel with `pstore` enabled and check the kernel log in recovery: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213460/218526. But nothing will appear there if the kernel doesn't boot at all. Just make sure that your zImage and boot.img formats are correct.

Comment: It's already enable.
Unfortinatly, "/sys/fs/pstore" im twrp is empty

Comment: the z in *"**z**Image"* indicates gzip compressed kernel

Answer (score 0):

according to this link you forgot to append dtb. replace Image.lz4-dtb in the zip and flash from TWRP
https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/kernel-sunfish-09-apr-holydragon-kernel-10-stable-11-stable.4155283

Comment: Thanks, 
I'm doing pack and unpack boot.img correctly !
I tested it with packing and unpacking with the old boot
It's looking the kernel source is the root cause !
For example(according to the post in [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/kernel-sunfish-09-apr-holydragon-kernel-10-stable-11-stable.4155283)): 
1. I tried to flash the "HDK_Sunfish-11_R.V.8.0" and it doen't boot correctly
2. I tried to flash the "HDK_Sunfish-10_R.V.1.1" and it boot correctly !

Comment: Next, I pulled the config.gz from "/proc" and compared it with my source kernel configuration and I found a lot of difference related to kernel modules.
After changing (=m) to (=y) the device boot correctly exclude touch screen.
Could you forward me to official (google) working and tested kernel 
Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure? In your question you said *'Image.lz4'* but in my answer I say *'Image.lz4-**dtb**'* I guess there is a difference (not sure if related to touchscreen)

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-pixel-4a-5g-pixel-5-factory-images-kernel-source-code

Comment: Yes, I'm sure !
It's not meter what when I'm doing repacking of Image.lz4 with ./mkbootimg --kernel <zImage.lz4 file> --dtb <dtb file> -- ..... or replacing Image.lz4-dtb in any kernel and flashing I getting the same result

Comment: In addition, the link you sent is to kernel release,
I want the source to build my custom stable kernel

Comment: *"Google uploads factory images, device tree, **kernel source code** for Pixel 4a 5G and Pixel 5"* https://www.xda-developers.com/google-pixel-4a-5g-pixel-5-factory-images-kernel-source-code

Comment: maybe links blocked in your country - use dns to by-pass